# VBA Macro to Copy Range and Paste range to PPT as Picture

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Need help to copy range of cells from excel sheet1 to PowerPoint file and paste it as Picture and make that picture fit inside the slide automatically.

I currently use Snagit software to take screenshot of the sheet and use send to powerpoint but it take lots of time.

Any feedback would be nice to automate this process

Comment: Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("A1:D4").CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

Comment: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/XL_PPT.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I will read more on implementing what you posted.

Comment: I tried that it worked but there is problem it is copying it as picture. Which causes loss of color in Picture. It would be better solution if I can copy in regular format in excel and paste as Picture in PPT. can someone suggest something?

Comment: the best i found was copying the range and using the pastespecial option in powerpoint to paste as a Picture(enhanced metafile)

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
Sub BetterPicturePaste()

    '...other stuff...

    Windows(1).Sheets(1).Range("myrange").Copy
    Windows(2).View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

End Sub
```